# Plugin Activation with TGM Plugin Activation library

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I added the TGM Plugin Activation library to my custom Wordpress theme. I listed all the required plugins. Also, I added my custom plugin to the required plugin list (which is stored on my own server). But I want to verify a token before the user can download the plugin.

I try to pass the token through the source URL.

```
[
    'name'     => esc_html__( 'My Theme Toolkit', 'text-domain' ),
    'slug'     => 'my-theme-toolkit',
    'source'   => 'https://example.com/tooklkit-plugins/?token=here_is_token',
    'required' => true,
    'version'  => '1.0.0',
]
```

And try to get a token from the URL and verify it. If the token is valid I pass the plugin URL with readfile() function.

```
$expected_token = 'here_is_token';

// Check if the token is valid.
if ( isset( $_GET['token'] ) && $_GET['token'] === $expected_token ) {

    // Token is valid, allow user to download plugin.
    $plugin_url = 'https://example.com/plugins/my-theme-toolkit.zip';

    header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
    header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary" );
    header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"my-theme-toolkit.zip\"" );

    readfile( $plugin_url );

} else {

    echo 'Invalid or missing token. Please contact support for assistance.';
}
```

But it's not working. Its returns "The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10): Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature".

Comment: Use `file_get_contents()` instead of `readfile()`

Comment: I have tried this one also but got the same response.